# Lightning Data Service will not load record

Tags: lightning-data-service

I just refreshed my dev sandbox and my staging sandbox. In my dev, lightning data service is able to load the record. When I go into my staging environment, which is a partial copy sandbox, no record will load, I will get the `ERRROR` changeType in my `handlePrescription`.

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller="CallerAppController">

    <aura:attribute name="prescription" type="Case" />


    <force:recordData aura:id="prescriptionEditor" 
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
                      targetFields="{!v.prescription}" 
                      fields="Id,CaseNumber"
                      mode="EDIT" 
                      recordUpdated="{!c.handlePrescription}" />

</aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
handlePrescription: function(component, event, helper) {

    console.log(component.get("v.recordId")); // returns an id
    let prescription = component.get("v.prescription");
    let eventParams = event.getParams();
    console.log(eventParams.changeType);
    if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
        //helper.reload(component);
    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {            
        //console.log("Prescription has loaded successfully.");
        //console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prescription)));

    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {

    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "REMOVED") {
        // record is deleted
        //console.log("Record was removed.");
    }
},
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: are you able to view that record in SOQL , and classic UI?

Comment: Yes. I'm also able to view the record in the standard UI.

Comment: can you post the error verbatim? Also is it Spring 19 or Winter 19?

Comment: Have you checked the profile permissions?

Comment: I don't see an error message. That is my problem. I don't know what the error is. Winter 19

Comment: @Robs, the profile is identical in both my dev and staging, because they both were refreshed yesterday. I don't think it's a profile issue

Comment: OK. And you are sure the field level permissions on the object are the same?

Comment: Is it a newly created record or the one you got from sandbox refresh?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal one I got from the sandbox refresh (existing data from prod).

Comment: @Robs I can soql the record and the fields in both my dev and uat

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the `recordId="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"` ?

Comment: Can you create a new record nd see? I have noticed sometimes sandbox copied record act funny

Comment: @Robs it does not.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal creating a new record does not work either.

Comment: @TylerZika I tried your code and it works in Spring 19 and Winter 19, without any issue. Can you just remove the apex controller and see if it works..

Comment: @PranayJaiswal no deal after your suggestions. Thanks for your help. I've opened a case with Salesforce support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is, but in refreshing my partial sandbox, I forgot to activate it. Once activated, Lightning Data Service started working...